# Line Highlights but dots dont

Tags: d3.js

Im trying to add a 'highlight' effect that is shown in this link(https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/parallel_custom.html) My lines are made up of two things, first is the line itself, and the second are dots that appear on each line. When my mouse hovers on the red line, the line stays the same but the red dots disapear for some reason. I want the red dots along with the red line to stay the same when i hover over it. What am i doing wrong here? the picture below shows what happens when i hover over the red line, and as you can see the red dots disappear [image]

```
  // Highlight individual line and dots
  var highlight = function(d) {
      
      var selected_line = d.key
      
      // first every group turns grey
      svgObj.selectAll(".line")
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
        .style("opacity", "0.2")

      svgObj.selectAll(".dot")
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
        .style("opacity", "0.2")
  
      // Second the hovered line takes its color
      svgObj.selectAll("." + selected_line)
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style("stroke", color(selected_line))
        .style("opacity", "1")
      
      svgObj.selectAll("." + selected_line)
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style("stroke", color(selected_line))
        .style("opacity", "1")
      
  }

  // UnHighlight 
  var doNotHighlight = function(d) {
    
    svgObj.selectAll(".line")
        .transition().duration(200).delay(50)
        .style("stroke", function(d){ return( color(d.key))})
        .style("opacity", "1")
    
  }

  // Draw the line
  svgObj.selectAll(".line")
      .data(sumstat)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
        .attr("class", function (d) { return "line " + d.key} ) // 2 class for each line: 'line' and the group name
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
        .attr("stroke-width", 4.5)
        .attr("d", function(d){
          return d3.line()
            .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(+d.n); })
            (d.values)
        })
        //.on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
        //.on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
        //.on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})
        .on("mouseover", highlight)
        .on("mouseleave", doNotHighlight )
        
  // Draw dots on points
  svgObj.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("class", function (d) { return "dot " + d.key } ) // 2 class for each line: 'line' and the group name
          .style("fill","white")
          .style("stroke-width", "3px")
          .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.name) })
          .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.year); })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.n); })
          .attr("r", 5.5)
```

Comment: Can you turn your code into a runnable snippet? That will help elicit better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the data of `.line` and `.dot` is different, one is `sumstat` with `key` property, the other one is `data` without `key`. so the code

```
.append("circle")
.attr("class", function (d) { return "dot " + d.key } )
```

will return "dot undefined" for each circle's class.
And then in `highlight()` the selected dots will not be included.

I adjusted your code into a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x1zh60ky/47/), but you might change the bind data of `.line` and `.dot` consistently, to avoid such mistake after.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked! I used different data sets for line and dots because for lines, the data was nested with key{key:ashley values:[] and so on} and I couldnt use that data format for dots.